# How do I run a rails generator in a production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How do I run a rails generator in a production environment?

I would expect one of the following to work, but none of them do:

```
rails generate active_admin:assets production
rails generate production active_admin:assets
```

Comment: maybe try RAILS_ENV=production rails g active_admin:assets

Comment: Also rails g active_admin:assets RAILS_ENV=production. @ewiinnnnn your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run it in production like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails g active_admin:assets
```